# Azure DevOps CLI or API to get Organization Groups used in Projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps I got a group "[test]\PermissionChecking" at organization level and I want to move this group "[test]\PermissionChecking" from organization level to project level. To do this, first I want to figure out where and all this Group "[test]\PermissionChecking" is used in a Azure DevOps project.

Is there any API or CLI to figure, where and all these group "[test]\PermissionChecking" is used or we have check it manually only?

Comment: I suspect you could get all assignments through `az DevOps permission list --id / --subject id-of-the-group --recurse`

Comment: And then use `az devops security group membership list --id id-of-the-group --relationship memberof` to query where tho group is a member of another group.

Comment: Use `az devops security group list` to find the groups identifier for the above commands.

Comment: @jessehouwing i don't know how to interpret the result from command az DevOps permission list --id / --subject id-of-the-group --recurse. These are the NoteProperty I got after running the command acesDictionary, includeExtendedInfo, inheritPermissions and token

Comment: Can you update the question with the extra details you need?

Comment: Once a group is added at Org level, I can use this group anywhere inside the a project in the same org. I can use this group in Release Approvers or in Branching Policy Pull Request approvers or in any other teams inside the project. So i want to map where and all this group is used inside a project.

Comment: I get that. But you don't understand how to use the output from the tool. Can you show what data you have right now from running `az devops`?